# How to force redirect to a particular route in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dashboard where I have 4 different routes. When login user will be redirected to a route `/fillForm`. Until the user fills the form and submit, it should be force redirect to same route. How can I achieve this case? I tried using CanDeactivate, but don't know how can I do the usage in my fillForm.ts
Note: I don't want to hide the routes and display them on submit.

```
  <li>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/fillForm" routerLinkActive="mat-accent">Details</a>
  </li>.
  <li>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/manage" routerLinkActive="mat-accent">view and mange posts</a>
  </li>.
  <li>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/common" routerLinkActive="mat-accent">everyone</a>
  </li>.
```

app routing module

```
 { path: '/fillForm', component: FillFormComponent, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard] }
```

my CanDeactivate.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { CanDeactivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {

  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate,
                currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
                nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return component.canDeactivate();
  }
}
```

html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onRegisterSubmit(form)" [formGroup] = "form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" >
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">
</form>
```

fillForm.ts

```
submitted:false,
 onRegisterSubmit(form): void {
   if(form.valid){
   this.submitted=true;
   const username = form.value;
  // I will navigate to another page
  // since field is disabled, we need to use 'getRawValue'
  this.form.reset() // reset form to empty
  }
}
 canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if(!this.submitted){
    //stay on same page
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CanDeactivate Router guard, that we he will not be able to navigate away from this page, until you want.

```
    export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<FillFormComponent> {

  public submittedOnce = false;

      canDeactivate(component: FillFormComponent,
                    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
                    nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        if(component.submitted) {
          this.submittedOnce = true;
        }
        return this.submittedOnce;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I tried that but getting some errors. I did't understand the proper usage of that one

Comment: Updated my code. How can I use this in my `fillForm.ts` . I'm not understanding that

Comment: wait, let me check.

Comment: when do you want to allow to navigate away from form page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215254/discussion-between-manoj-sai-and-aakash-garg).

Comment: Hello Aakash. Can you help me with this?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/62690230/10928596